# Why is passing 'this' pointer directly to archive an error, but another pointer of same type is ok?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

Passing a `this` pointer assigned to another one works fine, but passing just it itself directly doesn't as below:

```
table_row* table_row::deserialize_row(std::string src_serialized_row) {
        std::stringstream ss(src_serialized_row);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        table_row * dest = this;
        ia >> dest; // this is fine, compiles.
        return dest;
    }
```

```
table_row* table_row::deserialize_row(std::string src_serialized_row) {
        std::stringstream ss(src_serialized_row);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        ia >> this; //error, >> operator does not match [error]
        return this;
    }
```

[[error]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akont.png)
I don't really understand this. I'm passing the same pointer in both code examples, right? Why would it be an error?

Comment: It's hard telling where the problem could be without looking at more code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Remember that just because something compiles it doesn't necessarily mean it's logically correct. Deserializing like this to a pointer doesn't feel right. usually `>>` operates on a reference to a value.

Comment: `is >> this`, is illegal for the same reason that `this = that;` is illegal. You can't assign to the `this` pointer.

Comment: thanks @john I realised exactly what i'm doing with >> operator and it makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is that `this` is a prvalue, and assigning it to `dest` would make it an lvalue.

I would assume that the operator looks something like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
boost::archive::text_iarchive& operator>>(
    boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia,
    T& archive_to
);
```

And an rvalue like `this` can't bind to the non-const lvalue reference, as it's trying to set the pointer to the deserialised value (probably not what you want).

Comment: Some other reading to help understand the above: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)